# Ubuntu: .bashrc has JAVA_HOME8 and JAVA_HOME11 configured but sudo update-java-alternatives --list shows only java 11

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and I just installed Java 11. Previously I used Java 8.

Terminal command `java --version` prints:

```
openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

.bashrc file contains:

```
JAVA_HOME8=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8.0_212
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME8/bin
JAVA_HOME11=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME11/bin
```

when I run command `sudo update-java-alternatives --list` I get:

```
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

this is my usr/lib/jvm folder:

```
user@ubuntu:/usr/lib/jvm$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Mar 17 13:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 117 root root 4096 Feb 23 16:14 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   21 Jan 25 16:03 java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64 -> java-11-openjdk-amd64
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 2047 Jan 25 16:03 .java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root 4096 Mar 17 13:29 java-11-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4096 May  7  2019 jdk-1.8.0_212
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Mar 17 13:29 openjdk-11
```

Not sure where is the inconsistency, but it is not working as intended. Can someone assist me?

Thank you.

Comment: *when I run command sudo update-java-alternatives --list I get:* I'm guessing that's because you didn't install the earlier Java with your package manager (never a good thing)
btw, I'm not certain about this but I seem to remember making the same observation (as a question) to you a few days ago

Comment: Doesn't the .bashrc determine which java my terminal uses, nevertheless from where I installed it ? Additional thing I discovered after posting the question: I set my `JAVA_HOME` value to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8.0_212`, but `java --version` shows java-11. 
Also, about your question: no, this is the first time I am posting anything about this, or similar, topics to stack overflow as a question/comment./

Comment: Sorry must have been someone else. My point is that you can't use update-java-alternatives and expect it to work with non-package-manager-installed javas. $PATH will determine which java the terminal sees. So if you want it to see 8, that must be first in $PATH